# ListView item foreground color with binding

Tags: c++, uwp

I have a listview with data template as below :

```
<ListView x:Name="errorListBox" Width="615" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="White" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Errors}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
          <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" Foreground="Red" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}" />
        </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I want to set different color for different TextBlock in it. Currently the foreground is set to "Red".

How can we bind the Foreground color with some property in uwp c++?

The Working c++ code following the accepted answer. This can be helpful for someone :

```
public ref class Error sealed
{
private:
    Platform::String^ m_error;
    Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::SolidColorBrush^ m_foreGround;

public:
    Error(Platform::String^ error, Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::SolidColorBrush^ colorBrush)
    {
        m_error = error;
        m_foreGround = colorBrush;
    }

    property Platform::String^ ErrorText
    {
        Platform::String^ get()
        {
            return m_error;
        }

        void set(Platform::String^ val)
        {
            m_error = val;
        }
    }

    property Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::SolidColorBrush^ Foreground
    {
        Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::SolidColorBrush^ get()
        {
            return m_foreGround;
        }
        void set(Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::SolidColorBrush^ brush)
        {
            m_foreGround = brush;
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: If each item should have an individual foreground color, you should bind the ListView to a collection of objects with an appropriate property, i.e. of type Brush (and of course also a string property for the text, e.g. called Message). Then write `Text="{Binding Message}" Foreground="{Binding Color}"`.

Comment: It's C++/WinRT or C++/CX app?

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT it's c++/CX. I accepted the answer from "touseefbsb". I will share the working code in c++/CX in edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to bind a collection to your listview and and each item in that collection will have a **SolidColorBrush** property which you will use to bind to the foreground of your textblock.

**c# code**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    ObservbleCollection<Error> Errors = new ObservableCollection<Error>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Errors.Add(new Error("errorText1",new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)));
        Errors.Add(new Error("errorText2",new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)));
        // keep adding errors to the errors collection.
    }
}

class Error
{
    public Error(string errorText, SolidColorBrush foreground)
    {
        ErrorText = error;
        Foreground = foreground;
    }
    public string ErrorText { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Foreground { get; set; }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<ListView x:Name="errorListBox" Width="615" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="White" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Errors}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate x:DataType="Error">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
          <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" Foreground="{x:Bind Foreground}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{x:Bind ErrorText}" />
        </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

for more details on binding listview with a data template you can refer to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/item-containers-templates) and a video tutorial [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-040-Data-Binding-to-the-GridView-and-ListView-Controls)

Comment: Actually i was working on c++/cx App. But your solution worked for me. I will share the solution in edit. Thanks a lot.

Comment: happy to help :)